# Limiting posix_mkfifo

Tags: php, posix, mkfifo

In PHP, there's a call: posix_mkfifo() which basically makes a fifo.  Is there a way to set a limit on this file/fifo?  Otherwise, if no one is pulling data out, it can grow unbounded.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/5218741/132382

Answer (score 1):

The named pipes created by mkfifo do not have a buffer on the filesystem.

That means: The fifo will *always* be zero bytes in length and doesn't consume any storage space (except metadata).
Hence, it cannot grow unbounded and there's no need to limit it.

When a process attempts to write bytes to the fifo, it will be *blocked* until another process reads these bytes.