# How to solve "Failed to set pipe buffer size"

Tags: python, ubuntu, multiprocessing, pipe, spyder

I have a maybe somewhat naive question regarding pipe and pipe buffer...

I am not-advanced user of Ubuntu... And I am having a strange warning message in a python project at spyder...

```
/home/<myuser>/anaconda3/envs/spyder/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wurlitzer.py:209: RuntimeWarning: Failed to set pipe buffer size
  warnings.warn("Failed to set pipe buffer size", RuntimeWarning)
```

I have not how to include a reproducible example here..., just the message... It is thrown in any code since started... but is just a warning and the codes appears to be running accordingly...

What that message means? And what should I do (or even what I have done wrong)?

I have not got reasonable result in a quick web search when I search the message associated with python or spider... I believe it can be related to Ubuntu because the [questions like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624071/pipe-buffer-size-is-4k-or-64k), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218741/set-pipe-buffer-size) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51636391/how-to-set-pipe-size-from-shell), so, not sure even if this is the correct place to make this question...

One of the packages I am using is `Pool` from `multiprocessing` (maybe it is related to multiprocessing)?...

I appreciate any help...

Comment: update `wurlitzer` to get a more descriptive warning message: https://github.com/minrk/wurlitzer/pull/58/commits

probably either permission error or `/proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size`

Comment: @Aaron, thank you for the recommendation. I tried to update. It says: Requirement already satisfied: wurlitzer in /home/<myuser>/anaconda3/envs/spyder/lib/python3.9/site-packages (3.0.2)

Comment: then get it from github... Author has evidently not uploaded the most recent version to PyPi. It's also a very small change, you could just type it in yourself..

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) As you said, this is just a warning, so you safely can ignore it. We'll try to hide it in our next version so users don't have to see it.